# Does GeoMesa accept only single-band images?

Tags: geomesa

According to https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/tree/master/geomesa-accumulo/geomesa-accumulo-raster the GeoMesa accepts only single-band images.

Therefore, in order to import to GeoMesa a colorful image I have to import (e.g.) 3 sing-band images (R, G, B)?

Answer (score 0):

That bit of the documentation appears to be wrong.  The tutorial here: http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-raster.html works through ingesting an example RGB GeoTiff using GDAL and the GeoMesa command line tools.